# mysql entity framework 6 "field is required" error while inserting new record

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, insert

I am getting error when I try to insert a record to table.

Please not that I am using MySQL Entity Framework.

model:

```
public class products {
    public string ArtNo { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Diagram:

```
<EntityType Name="products">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="ArtNo" />
    </Key>
    <Property Name="ArtNo" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Title" Type="varchar" Nullable="false" />
    <Property Name="Description" Type="longtext" Nullable="false" />
</EntityType>
```

Code:

```
        using(mydbEntities d = new mydbEntities()) {
            products newProduct = new products();
            newProduct.ArtNo = "x001";

            d.products.Add(newProduct);
            try {
                d.SaveChanges();
            } catch(System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex) {
                System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

                foreach(var failure in ex.EntityValidationErrors) {
                    sb.AppendFormat("{0} failed validation\n", failure.Entry.Entity.GetType());
                    foreach(var error in failure.ValidationErrors) {
                        sb.AppendFormat("- {0} : {1}", error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
                        sb.AppendLine();
                    }
                }

                throw new System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException(
                        "Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:\n" +
                        sb.ToString(), ex
                ); // Add the original exception as the innerException
            }
        }
```

error:

```
{"Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:
myMVC.DBModel.products failed validation
- Title : The Title field is required.
- Description : The Description field is required.
"}
```

when I try with mysqlcommand I got no error:

```
MySqlCommand c = new MySqlCommand(con);
c.CommandText = "insert into products (artno) values ('x001')";
c.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**EDIT:**

I think entity framework generates SQL statement like this:

```
insert into products (ArtNo,Title,Description) values ('x001',NULL,NULL)
```

But, Title and Description fields are "non-nullable"; then it throws an error. (default values are empty string.)

I don't set Title and Description properties, so I expect SQL statement like this:

```
insert into products (ArtNo) values ('x001')
```

Comment: Could you show your model with attributes ?

Comment: edited; I have added model. It has no attr

Comment: Your products class is partial. Are there attributes in the other partial? Has the field been specified as required using the FluentAPI?

Comment: I have added some info and removed 'partial'

Answer (score 1):

It is because in your `EntityType Name="products"` declaration, both fields you mentioned are marked `nullable="false"`.  Hence EF returns that error. When you run `mysqlcommand`, the call does not go through EF layer.